# Projection from general point on cubic surface has smooth branch locus

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\phi: \text{Bl}_P(X) \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^2$ be the morphism induced by projection from a general point $P$ on a cubic surface $X$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$.

Is it true that the branch locus of $\phi$ (which is a quartic plane curve) is smooth? If so, why?

Comment: This is proved on p. 546 of Griffiths and Harris.